# How to handle URLs like node/%.atom?

Tags: routes

I am writing a module to generate a custom Atom feed, and I want to create URLs like http://drupalsite/node/20.atom or http://drupalsite/content/nodealias.atom.

I was trying to implement it as follows, but of course it is not correct.

```
$items['node/%.atom'] = array(
        'title' => 'atom node feed',
        'page callback' => 'atom_node_feed',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array('generate atom feed'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
```

Is it at all possible to create URLs like this in Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another user asked a very similar question on S.O. earlier: [How to add .html extensions in Drupal project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344411/how-to-add-html-extensions-in-drupal-project/6344620#6344620)

You could try using the [Pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to create aliases for your URLs, simply adding on the `.atom` at the end. More on Pathauto:

> The Pathauto module automatically generates path aliases for various kinds of content
>   (nodes, categories, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. 
>   This allows you to get aliases like `/category/my-node-title.html` instead of
>   `/node/123`. The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system which the administrator can
>   control.
>
> Pathauto depends on the [Token module](http://drupal.org/project/token). See screenshots of the [bulk delete](http://drupal.org/node/189458) and
>   the [admin settings screen](http://drupal.org/node/189459). View a screencast of 
>   [Using Pathauto and Views to get Index Aliases](http://drupal.org/node/247205).

Answer (score 6):

The code you wrote doesn't work because you are using a placeholder in the definition of the menu callback; such placeholders can be of two types:

- anonymous placeholder. The placeholder is just *%*, which matches any string.
- named placeholder. In this case, the placeholder is similar to *%node*, *%user*, used from Drupal core modules. If the placeholder is, for example, *%node*, Drupal will look for the `node_load()` function, and will pass it the string that in the path replaces the placeholder; when the function returns `FALSE`, then Drupal will return a 404 error page to the user. As the string following the *%* is used as name of the load function, to which the string "_load" is appended, characters that are not allowed in a function name are discarded (PHP cannot have a function with a name like `.atom_load()`.

If your purpose is to define a menu callback for your module that returns an atom feed for the node, then I would define the callback as the following:

```
$items['node/%node/atom'] = array(
  'title' => 'atom node feed',
  'page callback' => 'atom_node_feed',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access callback' => 'user_access',
  'access arguments' => array('generate atom feed'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

The page callback will get the node object as first argument, not the node ID.

To create a path like http://drupalsite/node/20.atom, you need to create a path alias. 
You can assign path aliases using the administrative page at admin/config/search/path (Drupal 7) or admin/build/path (Drupal 6).
Using Drupal 7, a module can create a path alias calling [path_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/path_save/7).
You can also use [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to automatically set path aliases for nodes. The module uses tokens that allows to dynamically create path aliases that follows a defined schema. As far as I know, node path aliases are just set for paths like node/1; the path alias is not set for a path like node/1/edit, or node/1/atom.