# How to have an extension in hook_menu()

Tags: routes, hooks

I am trying to create a menu with a file extension in `hook_menu()` with the following code:

```
$items['pdf/products/%.pdf'] = array(
    'title' => 'Download PDF',
    'page callback' => '_pdf_get',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
);
```

It works fine without the .pdf.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle URLs like node/%.atom?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5152/how-to-handle-urls-like-node-atom)

Comment: The answer to this question has been already provided in another question; the difference is the extension, but the answers given for that question already cover this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need the .pdf part in the hook menu?  Can't you just perform a check on the arg() function in your _pdf_get function to ensure that the argument contains ".pdf" and if not, redirects the user to the url with ".pdf" appended?